# Swift 4 Conversion error - NSAttributedStringKey: Any

Tags: swift4

I converted my app recently and I keep getting the error

> "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]?'

`barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)`

Whole code:

```
 class func getBarButtonItem(title:String) -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: title, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] as! [String : Any]
    barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

    return barButtonItem
}
```

Answer (score 52):

## Why you got this error

Previously, your `attributes` is defined as `[String: Any]`, where the key comes from `NSAttributedStringKey` as a string or `NSAttributedString.Key` in Swift 4.2

During the migration, the compiler tries to keep the `[String: Any]` type. However, `NSAttributedStringKey` becomes a struct in swift 4. So the compiler tries to change that to string by getting its raw value.

In this case, `setTitleTextAttributes` is looking for `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` but you provided `[String: Any]`

## To fix this error:

Remove `.rawValue` and cast your `attributes` as `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]`

Namely, change this following line

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue:
    UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!, 
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] as! [String : Any]
```

to

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:
    UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!, 
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] as! [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]
```

And in Swift 4.2,

```
 let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:
    UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!, 
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] as! [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]
```

Comment: You are a RockStar Man!

Comment: It still does not compile in Swift 4.2 `let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:
    UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!, 
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] as! [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]`

Answer (score 16):

Its expecting `NSAttributedStringKey`(`NSAttributedStringKey.font`) and you are sending `String`(`NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue`).

So please replace `NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue` with `NSAttributedStringKey.font` like below :

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: I get this warning. Is there is a solution?

Cast from '[NSAttributedStringKey : NSObject]' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: I used "let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]" and i still get the warning.

Comment: what is the warning?

Comment: Cast from '[NSAttributedStringKey : NSObject]' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Comment: For me its working. Can you please update the code how you are working.

Comment: All good now. Not sure what went wrong. I relaunched xcode and it faded.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in previous answers, `NSAttributedStringKey` was changed to a struct in Swift 4. However, other objects that *use* `NSAttributedStringKey` apparently didn't get updated at the same time.

The easiest fix, without having to change any of your other code, is to **append** `.rawValue` to *all* your occurrences of `NSAttributedStringKey` setters - turning the key names into `String`s:

```
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white
] as [String : Any]
```

Note that you won't need the `!` at the `as` now, either.

Alternatively, you can skip the `as` cast at the end by declaring the array to be `[String : Any]` upfront:

```
let attributes: [String : Any] = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white
]
```

Of course, you still need to append the `.rawValue` for each `NSAttributedStringKey` item you set.

Answer (score 3):

[leanne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292836/2941553) is correct for the cases where you still need to use `[String : Any]` and not `[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]`.

For example, in UIKit `UITextView.typingAttributes` is still of type `[String : Any]`. So for that property you have to use converted attributes (including custom ones):

```
let customAttributeName = "MyCustomAttributeName"
let customValue: CGFloat = 15.0

let normalTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] =
            [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0),
             NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue,
             NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor : UIColor.clear,
             NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: customAttributeName): customValue]

textView.typingAttributes = normalTextAttributes.toTypingAttributes()
```

where `toTypingAttributes()` is a function defined by extension in any of your project files:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == NSAttributedStringKey {
    func toTypingAttributes() -> [String: Any] {
        var convertedDictionary = [String: Any]()

        for (key, value) in self {
            convertedDictionary[key.rawValue] = value
        }

        return convertedDictionary
}
```