# Error setting 'foregroundColor' in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, nsattributedstring, nsattributedstringkey

In a macOS project using Swift 3.2, I'm trying to set the foreground color of a UITextView.

```
let placeHolderTitleString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter text here", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : NSColor.gray]) // error
```

The error I get is this:

> Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member
>   'foregroundColor'

The same code works fine in a Swift 4.0 project.

I'm trying to modify the code based on some answers I found for iOS [Swift 4 Conversion error - NSAttributedStringKey: Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314661/swift-4-conversion-error-nsattributedstringkey-any) but I continue to get errors. Is there a way to fix this without to update the project to Swift 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift 3 doesn't use the new Swift 4 `NSAttributeStringKey` values.

Use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` for the foreground color:

```
let placeHolderTitleString: NSAttributedString =
    NSAttributedString(string: "Enter text here", attributes:
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.gray])
```